# PHP - jquery ajax crop image before upload using croppie plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have written the code for cropping the image using PHP, jQuery, and Ajax with Croppie plugin.

I'm also trying to add the input value with it.
But I don't know how to post input value with ajax using PHP.
I mean to say when I'm a uploading image, I want input value also post with the image.

Please check with below code for your reference:-

```js
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
  enableExif: true,
  viewport: {
    width: 853,
    height: 292,
    type: ''
  },
  boundary: {
    width: 853,
    height: 292
  }
});

$('#upload').on('change', function () {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
      url: e.target.result
    }).then(function(){
      console.log('jQuery bind complete');
    });

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
  $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
  }).then(function (resp) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"image":resp},
      success: function (data) {
        html = '<img src="' + resp + '" />';
        $("#upload-demo-i").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/croppie.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/bootstrap-3.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/croppie.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
<div id="upload-demo" style="width:350px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="">
<div id="upload-demo-i" style="background:#e1e1e1;width:300px;padding:30px;height:300px;margin-top:30px"></div>
</div>
</div>-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top:30px;">
<strong>Select Image:</strong>
<br/>
<input type="file" id="upload">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="title">
<button class="btn btn-success upload-result">Upload Image</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['image'];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time().'.jpg';
file_put_contents('upload/'.$imageName, $data);

echo 'done';

?>
```

Comment: "_but it is not working_" it's not enought, you must describe clearly what's the problem in detail. Read [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Well read the field value and add it to the `data` object you're sending with your AJAX request ...

Comment: can you please help with some reference how to read the value and add it to the data?

Comment: @CBroe is this correct way to read the input value `data: {"image":resp,id1: $('#id1').val()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to know how to add the title to the `data` to post via Ajax?

That is easier than what you've already done!!
*if YOU've done it...*

Here is how:

```
data: {"title:":$("input[name='title']").val(),"image":resp}
```

You'll get the title using `$_POST['title']` on PHP side.

I've made a [**CodePen demo**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GmaZzV?editors=1011) where, obviously, Ajax is commented out...
But the data which would be sent is displayed in console.